# Use List comprehension instead of loop in python

Tags: python-2.7, list-comprehension

```
def interval(a,b,n):
    dx = float(b-a)/(n+1)
    cnt = 1
    points = [a]
    xj = a
    while cnt <= n+1:
        xj += dx
        points.append(xj)
        cnt+=1
    return points
```

Comment: Why do you need it as a list comprehension?

Comment: because list comprehension simple and short  than loop operations.

Comment: What is the question? Please make an attempt.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your function as given below :-

```
def interval(a,b,n):
    dx = float(b-a)/(n+1)
    points = [a]
    xj = a
    points.extend([xj + (i * dx) for i in xrange(1, n+2)])
    return points
```